# How to access the proxy.cgi file in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, tomcat, cgi

I am trying to use Openlayer in a WEB application based on spring framework. I need to use a cgi proxy on tomcat. I followed  the instruction here [installing-a-cgi-on-tomcat](http://www.berndresch.com/blog/2011/11/01/installing-a-cgi-proxy-on-tomcat/). It works with a simple web application. But I got problem to access the cgi file when I tried to implement it with Spring MVC. I got the warning message.

```
 WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:962 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pcms/app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
```

I tried many ways,but I didnt figure out how to access the proxy.cgi file under WEB-INF\cgi directory. Please help. Thanks.
Attached is the content of web.xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Property &amp; Configuration Management System</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>pcms.root</param-value>
  </context-param>
   <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.pb.redline.listener.MTAServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- proxy.cgi for openlayers -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>debug</param-name>
          <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
          <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <init-param>
          <param-name>executable</param-name>
          <param-value>C:/Python26/ArcGIS10.0/python.exe</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mapped `CGIServlet` to `/cgi-bin/*` and `DispatcherServlet` to `/app/*` - no surprise that request to `<contextPath>/app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi` is handled by Spring rather than by CGI.

Try `/pcms/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi` instead.

Comment: I used this one `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/pcms/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url="` ; and it is automatically mapped to `/pcms/app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi`. then the app cannot access the cgi file

Comment: @Alex: I see you use `UrlRewriteFilter`. You need to add an exclusion for `/cgi-bin/*` to its config.

Comment: Thanks. I added the exclusion rule in the urlrewrite.xml. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You don't install or use cgi proxy on Tomcat.

cgi is for apache server or IIS that are used as a front-end server. Tomcat may sit behind it. The configuration of Apache is detailed in: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Be warned that OpenLayers warns that its proxy.cgi is only an example and may not have good enough check to stop it from being exploited, i.e. it may run some malicious script.

If you are serving your OpenLayers client page on Tomcat alone and it contains layers from other GeoServer or Mapserver, you can use proxy servlet and specify it as:

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "sevlet URL on the server that served this page";

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/ServletProxy

https://svn.openxdata.org/Experimental/openXmapper/trunk/gwt-openlayers-server/src/main/java/org/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/server/GwtOpenLayersProxyServlet.java